# SAPUI5: How to retrieve id of a control (eg: Label/toobar) defined in a view into a controller in a function?

Tags: sapui5

I need to retrieve id of a control (VBox which has `id="multipleChoiceQuestion"`) and need to hide it on button press.

How to do this?

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
displayBlock="true" controllerName="opensap.onlinequestionnaire.controller.App" height="100%">
<VBox id="multipleChoiceHolder">
    <HBox width="700px" backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center" id="mCHorHolder1">
        <CheckBox id="checkBox1"/><Label text="{questionnaire>/data/0/answers/0}" id="multipleChoice1"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller){

    Controller.extend("opensap.onlinequestionnaire.controller.App", {
        goToNext:function() {
            alert("Next Question");
            alert(this.byId('multipleChoiceQuestion'));                         
        }
    });
});
```

In my `goToNext:function()` I would like to retrieve the id of the VBox and would like to hide it.

I tried alerting `this.byId()` but it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the VBox:

```
// id as stated in the description
oVBox = this.getView().byId("multipleChoiceQuestion");

// or
// id as stated in the view in the code sample
oVBox = this.getView().byId("multipleChoiceHolder");
```

Set visibility:

```
oVBox.setVisible(false);
```

By the way, the id's of your post description and the view in your post's code sample are not identical. But I'm sure you're aware of this minor mix-up which has nothing to do with your question of a general approach to retrieve and hide a control. Just wanted to mention it to be on the safe side

Comment: Thank you. Why do we need to use getView() ? Because when I did **this.byId("multipleChoiceHolder").setVisible(false)**  
It worked.
I am new to UI5 so trying to understand the basics.

Comment: Hm, you don't really need it in newer versions of UI5, see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#byId : "Returns an Element of the connected view with the given local ID."

Comment: I use it for the course of clarity. GetId() does just the same as getView().getId()

Comment: @Nabi          Thank you it was helpful.

Comment: @no1dea        Thank you for the help.

Comment: @loki Well, this is not the right answer to the question because the initial issue was caused by the fact you used the wrong id in this.byId(...)! Even in this answer the wrong id (="multipleChoiceQuestion") is used.

Comment: @Nabi. Hey ya you are right. But I got the context and made changes accordingly. The right Id was multipleChoiceHolder.
I needed to know how to retrieve an Id of a Control in a controller and how to hide it, which you answered perfectly so I marked it as answer accepted.

Comment: Hi nabi it worked with this.by(selecting correct id) and then chaining the setVisible(false). In the answer suggested by no1dea the id selected is incorrect but the other things are correct.
@no1dea Can you please edit the id of your answer to "multipleChoiceHolder" so that it becomes perfect answer. :) Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The ID of your VBox is "multipleChoiceHolder" and not "multipleChoiceQuestion". So, shouldn't it be **this.byId('multipleChoiceHolder')** instead of **this.byId('multipleChoiceQuestion')**?

Comment: Yes. I made the change and it worked. But is this the way you do it or you use also getView() mentioned by no1dea?

Comment: Again, you should not need getView() in newer versions of UI5. What version do you use? Also, why does the other version work for you although it uses the wrong id ("multipleChoiceQuestion")?